# Signing APK by commandline

Tags: android, command-line, apk, jarsigner

I am developing android applications with Eclipse and the Android SDK. For testing the app on a device it is pretty embarrasing to do the same job every time:

- Android Tools
- Export Signed Application Package
- Select project
- Select keystore
- Use password
- Select alias
- Use password
- Select output path & file

After that using commandline and adb to uninstall previous version of the installed app. Then installing new version of the app.

As this way is mich too long I wanted to script the whole action, but the `jarsigner` is always stopping with same error and I can't sign the apk.

`unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 761 but got 763 bytes)`

At this point I am pretty confused. The `jarsigner` is from JDK 1.6.0.26. Eclipse is at Version 3.6.2. Android SDK is complete up-to-date. I am working under Windows Vista 32-bit.

Has anyone similar problems with the `jarsigner` or can give me some tips?!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just debug the app on your phone?

This is how to do it:

1. First, download and install your phone's drivers (find via a Google search)
2. Debug the project in eclipse as you would on an emulator in eclipse, but when eclipse tells you to choose a device, pick your phone.

This way, you won't have to export the app, and you can debug on a decent device - i.e. not an emulator.

Comment: The way to directly debug on the phone is using unsigned apps. That is what I normally do. My app now uses google maps and therefor needs signed apps to work correctly.

Comment: @FlyBy, your app is still signed when you debug on the phone - it's signed with your debug key that is auto-generated for you. Just generate a Maps API key based on your debug key as described in http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint

Comment: @RivieraKid yes, that makes sense. I knew that it was signed with a debug key, but didn't know that it must be registered for maps. Nice answer!

Comment: @RivieraKid, nice! That is what I needed! Thank you very much! Accepted and voted up! :D